# IntelliJ macOS Mojave - Moving Java Class into another Package does not consider JSON Files

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ 2018.3.4 with default settings on macOS Mojave 10.14 for a spring boot project containing JSON files for data population. Refactoring Package names for Java-Classes (move a class into existing package) does not consider JSON files.

[IntellJ Moving Java Class in another package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0w5T5.png)

I've already tried to change the file extension into *.txt or *.html, after this change the refactoring seems to work. Changed package name occurs in those files.

```
Java class: com.test.MyClass

Json file (src/main/resources/file.json):

{
  "name" : "com.test.MyClass"
}
```

After changing the Package name into "com.test2.MyClass", the "name" property in src/main/resources/file.json is expected to be changed into the same value "com.test2.MyClass".

Comment: What's the "scope" of the search? You can see it by clicking on Settings icon on the preview tool window

Comment: I've tried "Project Files", "All Places" and module. All of them do not work

Comment: See my last comment in the answer.

Comment: @Vitalij please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If the issue is reproducible with it on other machines and it's not some configuration problem, I'd file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Comment: I have the same issue on my private and on my mac at work: 
Project: https://github.com/vbliferniz/missingjson
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-207027

Answer (score 0):

When you rename a variable/property/class/method/package in IntelliJ IDEA, you're given a choice to search over strings and text occurrences. This will do the trick

[image]

To change the scope, use the Preview button.

[image]

To move a class to another package, use the Move refactoring action.

[image]

Comment: Two problems with this Solution:
1. It still does not work for json files 
2. In cases of moving multiple Classes into same package, it works exactly one time, after that I get the Error "File already exists"

Comment: @Vitalij Which problems?

Comment: @Vitalij using the Preview, allow you to set the Scope of the search, and then re-run it. It works because I use it all the time.

Comment: Thank you for the efforts I do really appreciate. I've also already tried to change the Scope to Project Files and module but it still does not work. The weird thing is, if I change the file extension from json into txt it works perfectly fine. :(

Comment: @Vitalij let me think what could be the problem. Have you checked the files exclusion? In the module settings

Comment: Module setting "exclude files" does not contain any entries.

Comment: @Vitalij than I have no idea